# iOS Beacon monitoring - RegionLeft is not fired

Tags: ios, xamarin, bluetooth, beacon

I implemented the `CLLocationManager.StartMonitoring()` method. The `CLLocationManager.EnterRegion` is fired when the beacon comes into the range of the phone, however the `RegionLeft` does not get called when the Beacon is outside of the range of the phone again. I use the following code:

```
public void StartWakeupForBeacon()
    {
        //NSOperationQueue.MainQueue.AddOperation(() =>
        //{
        string message = "";
        CLProximity previousProximity = CLProximity.Far;
        var userId = ServiceLocator.Instance.Get<IAccountStoreService>().GetAccountUserId();
        var tupple = UtilHelper.GetMajorMinorFromUserId(userId);
        var major = tupple.Item1;
        var minor = tupple.Item2;

        var beaconUuid = UuidHelper.BeaconUuidString;
        BeaconRegion = new CLBeaconRegion(new NSUuid(beaconUuid), (ushort)major, (ushort)minor, "com.example.company");
        BeaconRegion.NotifyEntryStateOnDisplay = true;
        BeaconRegion.NotifyOnExit = true;
        BeaconRegion.NotifyOnEntry = true;

        LocationManager = new CLLocationManager();
        LocationManager.RequestAlwaysAuthorization();

        LocationManager.RegionEntered += (object sender, CLRegionEventArgs e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("region entered");
            var btService = ServiceLocator.Instance.Get<IBluetoothService>();
            ServiceLocator.Instance.Get<ILoggingService>().LogEvent(LoggingService.BeaconRegionEnteredEvent);
            btService.ExchangeData();
        };

        LocationManager.RegionLeft += (object sender, CLRegionEventArgs e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("region left");
            ServiceLocator.Instance.Get<ILoggingService>().LogEvent(LoggingService.BeaconRegionLeftEvent);
        };



        LocationManager.DidDetermineState += (object sender, CLRegionStateDeterminedEventArgs e) =>
        {

            switch (e.State)
            {
                case CLRegionState.Inside:
                    Console.WriteLine("region state inside");
                    break;
                case CLRegionState.Outside:
                    Console.WriteLine("region state outside");
                    break;
                case CLRegionState.Unknown:
                    Console.WriteLine("region unknown");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("region state unknown");
                    break;
            }
        };
        LocationManager.DidStartMonitoringForRegion += (object sender, CLRegionEventArgs e) =>
        {
            LocationManager.RequestState(e.Region);
            string t_region = e.Region.Identifier.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(t_region);
        };
        LocationManager.DidRangeBeacons += (object sender, CLRegionBeaconsRangedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (e.Beacons.Length > 0)
            {
                CLBeacon beacon = e.Beacons[0];
                switch (beacon.Proximity)
                {
                    case CLProximity.Immediate:
                        message = "Immediate";
                        break;
                    case CLProximity.Near:
                        message = "Near";
                        break;
                    case CLProximity.Far:
                        message = "Far";
                        break;
                    case CLProximity.Unknown:
                        message = "Unknown";
                        //SendNotication();
                        break;
                }

                if (previousProximity != beacon.Proximity)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                }
                previousProximity = beacon.Proximity;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("nothing");
            }
        };
        LocationManager.StartMonitoring(BeaconRegion);
        LocationManager.MonitoringFailed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Failed monitoring");
        };
        LocationManager.StartRangingBeacons(BeaconRegion);
        //});
    }
```

When the Beacon is out of range of the phone, I can see that this is recognized by the app, since `DidRangeBeacon` does not recognize any beacon anymore and prints "nothing" to the console.

Additionally I get weird device logs regarding the location manager, it basically spams the following warning:

```
#Warning Tried injecting when not running
```

Comment: It takes 30 seconds for a region exit to fire after the last beacon detection with ranging.  Have you waited that long?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have waited around 15 minutes while the app was open, it did not detect the region exit event. Right now I try to figure out if the problem is within my implementation or if it is a problem with iOS. I Use the Locate App to keep track of that beacon. Here sometimes the exit region is fired, however it seems to be really unreliable. Have you made any experience with implementing beacon monitoring on iOS? Did it work for you reliably?